# npm ERR! missing script: start on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

Hello I am trying to deploy an application to heroku through my github. I modified the start script inside the package.json to go inside the src file where there is the app.js that should be the server side file.

This is my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js src/app.js --exec 'npm run lint && node'",
    "lint": "eslint \"**/*.js\"",
    "start": "node src/app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.23.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.8.0"
  }
}
```

This is the file directory:

[image: File directory]

And this is the code inside the app.js file:

```js
console.log("hello")
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan')

const app = express()

app.use(morgan('combine'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors())

app.get('/status', (req,res)=>{
    res.send({
        message: 'hello world!'
    })


})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081)
```

The full error message that I got from Heroku is:

```
2021-04-02T15:36:38.339680+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-04-02T15:36:43.511317+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-04-02T15:36:43.688509+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-04-02T15:36:43.392349+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2021-04-02T15:36:43.424949+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-02T15:36:43.425845+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-04-02T15:36:43.426219+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-04-02T15_36_43_393Z-debug.log
2021-04-02T15:36:44.616474+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tft-training-tool.herokuapp.com request_id=7c11d9b2-66b5-4daf-ba1d-ad3c22e0706a fwd="90.255.93.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-02T15:36:44.843068+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tft-training-tool.herokuapp.com request_id=3411084a-5fa2-4563-96b9-879b3735f80a fwd="90.255.93.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: May it be a problem that I am deploying it through github but the package.json is not in the main directory it is under the server folder?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a folder with `package.json` and `package-lock.json` which is the root folder that contains two other folders `client` and `server` which have their own `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files (at least the **server** folder as I see in the image above, so you're configured scripts for the server inside `package.json` inside server folder obiviously. Because Heroku pulls all the repository together, it takes the `package.json` inside the `root` folder as configuration to your server, which seems like doesn't contain `start` script.